# Agregar firebase a Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification

He agregado `Firebase` para las notificacion y ni apicación ya no corre

me dice que debo usar una version superior a  `33` pero es la versión actual maxima

este es el gradle

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pokestore.poke_store"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.2')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

el pub

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^0.13.5
  provider: ^6.0.3
  badges: ^2.0.3
  firebase_messaging: ^13.0.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.9.0
  firebase_analytics: ^9.3.3
```

El error

```
One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to E:\Android\poke_store\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
  compileSdkVersion 33
  ...
}
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Unable to delete file 'E:\Android\poke_store\build\app\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug\R.jar'

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: intentaste hacer un flutter clean?

Answer (score 0):

Debes ir a tu archivo `app\build.gradle` y definir

```
compileSdkVersion  32
```

Asegura también que no exista una versión mayor a 32 en tu proyecto, debes cambiar por ejemplo también targetSdkVersion :

```
targetSdkVersion 32
```